# Amazon Connect CCP - capture logout link

Tags: amazon-connect

i need help to Capture the action of the "Logout" Button in Amazon Connect CCP so I can have a shortcut to logout once click on it without going to settings then click logout

[image: CCP Logout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md#logging-out) you can log out the agent by visiting the logout endpoint (`/connect/logout`).